# Maximum sub-array sum

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, array, divide-and-conquer

My code finds the maximum subarray sum and the starting and ending index of that subarray.

```
int Max(int a,int b){return (a>b)?a:b;}
int Max(int a,int b,int c){return Max(Max(a,b),c);}
int MaxAcrossSubArray(int arr[],int l,int m,int r,int &Start,int &End) 
{
    Start=m;//initialize start index
    int sum=arr[m];
    int sum_l=arr[m];
    for(int i=m-1;i>=l;--i)//include mid(---------|)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];
        if(sum>sum_l)
        {
            Start=i;
            sum_l=sum;
        }

    }
    End=m+1;//initialize end index
    sum=arr[m+1];
    int sum_r=arr[m+1];
    for(int i=m+2;i<=r;++i)//include mid(|-----------------)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];
        if(sum>sum_r){
            End=i;
            sum_r=sum;
        }
    }
    return sum_l+sum_r;//(-----------|---------------------)

}
int MaxSubArray(int arr[],int l,int r,int &Start,int &End)
{
    if(l==r)
    {
        Start=l;
        End=r;
        return arr[l];
    }

    else
    {
       int mid=(l+r)/2;
        int sA=-1,eA=-1,sB=-1,eB=-1,sC=-1,eC=-1;
        int a=MaxSubArray(arr,l,mid,sA,eA);
        int b=MaxSubArray(arr,mid+1,r,sB,eB);
        int c=MaxAcrossSubArray(arr,l,mid,r,sC,eC);
        int Maximum=Max(a,b,c);

        if(Maximum==a)
        {
            Start=sA;
            End=eA;
            return a;
        }

        else if(Maximum==b)
            {
                Start=sB;
                End=eB;
                return b;
            }
        else
            {
                Start=sC;
                End=eC;
                return c;
            }
    }
    }

}
int main()
{
    int arr[9]={-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4};
    int Start=-1;
    int End=-1;


    cout<<MaxSubArray(arr,0,8,Start,End)<<"\n";
    cout<<Start<<"\n";
    cout<<End<<"\n";
    for(int i=Start;i<=End;++i)
    {

        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete program.  You seem to be missing some `#include` lines - if you [edit] to add them, we'll have a complete program that we could compile and run.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review!

## Algorithm

Since you specifically asked how to optimize the code, I'll put this part first.  You are using a divide-and-conquer algorithm.  This algorithm is \$\operatorname{\Theta}(n \log n)\$.  There's a better \$\Theta(n)\$ algorithm which works like this: go through the array, from index `i = [0, n)`.  Keep track of two variables:

- `max_sum`: maximum subarray sum so far.
- `max_end_sum`: maximum subarray sum ending at index `i`.

Initially, both can be considered to be "negative infinity".  At each element, these variables can be updated in constant time with the following formulas:

```
new_max_sum     = max{max_sum, array[i], max_end_sum + array[i]}
new_max_end_sum = max{array[i], max_end_sum + array[i]}
```

## Readability

Code is read more than written.  Here are some tips to improve readability:

- Always put a space after a comma and around binary operators.  Instead of

  ```
  int c=MaxAcrossSubArray(arr,l,mid,r,sC,eC);
  ```

  Use

  ```
  int c = MaxAcrossSubArray(arr, l, mid, r, sC, eC);
  ```
- Always put the opening and closing braces of a function body on separate lines.  Instead of

  ```
  int Max(int a,int b){return (a>b)?a:b;}
  ```

  Use

  ```
  int Max(int a, int b)
  {
      return (a > b) ? a : b;
  }
  ```
- Put a space after control keywords like `for` or `if`.  This helps visually distinguish them from functions and operators (`sizeof`, `typeid`, etc.).
- Be consistent with indentation.  Bad example:

  ```
  if(Maximum==a)
  {
      Start=sA;
      End=eA;
      return a;
  }

  else if(Maximum==b)
      {
          Start=sB;
          End=eB;
          return b;
      }
  ```

## The standard library facilities

The function `Max` is already available in the standard library as `std::max`.  For example:

```
std::max(42, 420) == 420
std::max({42, 420, 4200}) == 4200
```

(You may noticed that you need to use braces if the number of arguments is not exactly two.)

The following loop:

```
for(int i=Start;i<=End;++i)
{

    cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
}
```

can be replaced by a call to `std::copy` with `std::ostream_iterator`.

In C++, raw C arrays are not recommended.  You are advised to use standard library containers like `std::array` instead.  Indexes should be of type `std::size_t` or `std::ptrdiff_t` instead of `int`.

Here's how the code may look like in modern C++, with iterators and tuples: (just a rough idea, not particularly optimized)

```
template <
    typename ForwardIt,
    typename Value,
    typename BinaryOp = std::plus<>,
    typename Compare = std::less<>
    >
std::tuple<ForwardIt, ForwardIt, Value>
maximum_subarray(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Value init,
                 BinaryOp combine = {}, Compare compare = {})
{
    auto max_sum = std::make_tuple(first, first, init);
    auto max_end_sum = std::make_tuple(first, init);

    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        auto& [it, value] = max_end_sum;
        value = combine(value, *first);
        if (compare(value, *first)) {
            it = first;
            value = *first;
        }
        if (compare(std::get<2>(max_sum), value)) {
            max_sum = {it, std::next(first), value};
        }
    }

    return max_sum;
}

template <typename ForwardIt>
auto maximum_subarray(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    using Value = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type;
    return maximum_subarray(first, last, Value());
}
```